# Random selection of polygon but with certain value

Tags: qgis, select, random

i'm using QGIS, and i have a multi polygon which has more then 6000 features with population data in it, so i want to select only 400 features randomly but the selected feature need to have a certain population sum, lets say around 20.000.000 people.

I've been using random selection but it only select 400 features randomly.

is there any other way?

Comment: Do u really mean a **( one ? )** multipolygon with 6000 sub-parts ? How many lines do you have in your attribute table ?

Comment: yes, i mean its a polygon of a country with borders in it, it has 6000 lines  (which is the city). and each city has different number of population.

Comment: So ... you're dealing with **two** layers ? a **country** layer with one feature (one polygon) and a **cities** layer with 6000 polygons ?

Comment: One layer only, the cities.

Comment: One layer of a country, which includes 6000 cities - right?

Comment: yup, Erik is right.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a subset of your data using your attribute column **"population"** (let's say population > 20.000.000).

Then you're able to use the `toolbox treatement` '**random extract**' (dont forget to tick selected features only) and choose the "number of selected features" option, i don't think there will be any selection limit ...

That should do the job ?

Comment: I think the keyword here is "sum" - they asked for the population *sum* to be >20 million.

Comment: you're completely right ... i overlooked that ... or read too quick ...